# How i can set section from code in Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

So, I know that I can render section with `@RenderSection("MySection")` and set his value with

```
@section MySection{
   <p>Some Html</p>
}
```

But how i can set section value from my model? Something like:

```
public void OnGet(){
   Model.SetSection("MySection", "<p>Some html</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sections in Razor views are typically defined directly within the view and are not set directly from the ViewModel. However, you can achieve similar results by setting a ViewModel property that holds the content you want to include within a section, and then rendering that content in the view using **@Html.Raw**, **AspNetCore.Html** or other appropriate techniques.
Let's me share two techniques with you:

1. **Using AspNetCore.Html**
   With this technique you strigify the Html content befor sent to view.

- Razor ViewModel class

  ```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;

    public class YourModel : PageModel
    {
        public HtmlString DynamicContent { get; private set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            string htmlContent = "<p>Some Html</p>";

            DynamicContent = new HtmlString(htmlContent);
        }
    }
  ```
- Razor View

  ```
     @model YourModel
     @section DynamicSection {
        @(Model.DynamicContent)
     }
  ```
- In the _Layout

  ```
  @await RenderSectionAsync("DynamicSection", required: false)
  ```

2. **Using @Html.Raw**

- In Razor ViewModel

  ```
    public class YourModel : PageModel
    {
        public string DynamicContent { get; private set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            DynamicContent = "<p>Some Html</p>";
        }
    }
  ```
- In Razor View

  ```
     @model YourModel
     @section DynamicSection {
        @Html.Raw(Model.DynamicContent)
     }
  ```
- In the _Layout

  ```
  @await RenderSectionAsync("DynamicSection", required: false)
  ```

Answer (score -1):

In Razor Pages, the @RenderSection directive is typically used to render sections defined in the layout file. Sections are usually populated within the Razor view file itself or through child pages using the @section syntax. However, setting section values directly from the model can be a bit unconventional since the separation of concerns might get blurred. Instead, you can use a different approach to achieve your goal.

One common approach is to use a ViewBag or ViewData to pass values from your model to the view, which can then be used to render content dynamically. Here's an example of how you could achieve something similar to what you're asking for:

In your Razor Page model:

```
public class MyModel : PageModel
{
    public string MySectionContent { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        MySectionContent = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
    }
}
```

In your Razor view:

```
@page
@model MyNamespace.MyModel

@{
    Layout = "_Layout"; // Assuming you have a layout file
}

@section MySection {
    @Html.Raw(Model.MySectionContent)
}

<!-- Rest of your view content -->
```